# Data Factory: How to parameterize url with date to fetch data for 10 days from current date

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a rest api url that consist of a date like `www.my_rest_api/2022-20-28`. I need to parameterize the date part so that every time ADF runs and calls the api, it will use the current date and the coming 10 days
Is this possible in ADF v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date formatted with this, you will probably want to add convertFromUtc() function to get into local timezone so date is correct.

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

then use this to get the url assuming theDate is the variable above.

```
@concat('www.my_rest_api/', variables('theDate'))
```

To do today and the following 10 days set a pipeline variable of array type with the value [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and then do a ForEach over the array.  This will get the url in each loop, just substitute your time zone.

```
@concat('www.my_rest_api/', formatDateTime(addDays(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Pacific Standard Time'), item()), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

By default ForEach loops run in parallel, if this causes issues with the API you can select the Sequential option in the ForEach Settings tab.

I did this using variables to verify but you can use this anywhere in your pipeline.

Comment: This approach only works for one date right? What I want is that it loops the url with the current day and the coming 10 days. `www.my_rest_api/2022-10-28`, `www.my_rest_api/2022-10-29`, `www.my_rest_api/2022-10-30` and so on.

Comment: you can use the adddays() with the above in a loop to get each day you want.

Comment: I updated answer to include how to do in a loop to get all the days.